# Office365/Sharepoint Online: Internal server error against the change events API call

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office365apis, changelog

I'm getting the following error against the API call that fetches the change logs for a OneDrive User

```
Status Code 401
{"error_description":"The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."}
```

My question is, how do I enable the trace for my Office365 subscription? as that's Sharepoint Online.

The API call

```
POST
https://<mysitecollection>/personal/some_user_domain_com/_api/web/getchanges
```

Please note that this tenant is NOT on the shared cloud for Office365.

Comment: If it is a dedicated cloud, then perhaps opening a ticket with support to see if they can enable it in your environment.